# Why do the docs switch from sbd to sbd1 here?

Tags: 16.04, iscsi

I'm following this ISCSI guide here:

https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/iscsi-initiator.html

At the bottom it mentions `sdb is the new iSCSI disk` however in the next commands it uses `sbd1`.

Why is this? Is this just a typo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

/dev/sdb (or, just sdb) is the device.

/dev/sdb1 (or, just sdb1) is the partition within the device to use.